# How to Compare Files in Visual Studio 2019 Horizontally?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I was trying to use the built in file comparison tool in visual studio 2019 and I dont see an option to display the files horizontally vs side by side. Any way to change this ? Thanks in advance for any replies.